# Css change dynamic value with jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I have a swipe with photos when you swipe it adds the width of your screen in the inline css: left: and if you don't swipe it swipes automatically every 5seconds

Now I want to multiply that (the screen width) by * 2.

```
$(function () {
  $(".contentHolder.ui-draggable").css({
    left: function( index, value ) {
      return parseFloat( value ) * 2;
    }
  });
});
```

It works on values that don't change after a few seconds.
If I do:

```
$(function () {
  $(".contentHolder.ui-draggable").css({
    width: function( index, value ) {
      return parseFloat( value ) * 2;
    }
  });
});
```

It works it does the math.

How can i make that this works on dynamic values?

Comment: parseFloat('620px') == > NAN

Comment: @Rajaprabhu, nope, that will return 620. Try it.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi oh.. i was in a thought like that.. just now tried that out in console.. returns the expected res..

Comment: When exactly the values are changing? are the values changing on resize of window?

Comment: Couldn't understand what exactly the problem is.  dynamic values?

Comment: Maybe you want to use the `$(window).resize()` event ? I don't really understand either

Comment: @MR_Green its a swipe with photos when  you swipe it adds the width of your screen in the left: and if you don't swipe it swipes automatically every 5seconds

Comment: i don't really know how to call it i thought dynamic would be the best word :P

Comment: @Rikato you should change the code exactly there itself.

Comment: @MR_Green thats the problem i can't

Comment: @MR_Green its i standard script and im not allowed to change so i made a custom.js

Comment: @Rikato then write another timer. not recommended but I can't see any other optimized solution in your case.

Comment: @MR_Green I also cant change it because there are other swipes that just have to work normally

Comment: @MR_Green its not about the timer but about how far the left is if screen iwdth is 600px i want left: to be 1200px But now it makes left: 600px